# how to create vertical menu and show their submenu on relative pages horizontally

Tags: html, css, menu

i have a hard time to create a navigation for my site where i wanted to show my menu like that:

- Menu 1
- Menu 2
- Menu 3
- Menu 4
- Menu 5

and their sub menu on their relative main menu pages horizontally like that:

```
  SubMenu 1.1 | SubMenu 1.2 | SubMenu 1.3 | SubMenu 1.4 | SubMenu 1.5 | ...
```

and i would like to mention here that i have a single page site that loads pages dynamically into a div with jquery ajax and those pages only contains some contents that i want to be there and there are no other extra contents or html tags like `<html>` `<head>` or `<body>` etc. so what i want? suppose when i click on `Menu 1` and when `Menu 1` loaded then their submenus like `SubMenu 1.1` upto `SubMenu 1.12` should be opened in that page horizontally at the same time menu 1 must remains active! please look at the picture below.
here is the code i have so far where insted of achiving this i got drop down as you can see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqeelpld/duagvm3h/8/)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Menu 1">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.1">SubMenu 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.2">SubMenu 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.3">SubMenu 1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.4">SubMenu 1.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.5">SubMenu 1.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.6">SubMenu 1.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.7">SubMenu 1.7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.8">SubMenu 1.8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.9">SubMenu 1.9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.10">SubMenu 1.10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.11">SubMenu 1.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.12">SubMenu 1.12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Menu 2">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.1">SubMenu 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.2">SubMenu 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.3">SubMenu 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.4">SubMenu 2.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.5">SubMenu 2.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.6">SubMenu 2.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.7">SubMenu 2.7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.8">SubMenu 2.8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.9">SubMenu 2.9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.10">SubMenu 2.10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.11">SubMenu 2.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.12">SubMenu 2.12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Menu 3">Menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.1">SubMenu 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.2">SubMenu 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.3">SubMenu 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.4">SubMenu 3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.5">SubMenu .5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.6">SubMenu 35.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.7">SubMenu 3.7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.8">SubMenu 3.8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.9">SubMenu 3.9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.10">SubMenu 3.10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.11">SubMenu 3.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.12">SubMenu 3.12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Menu 4">Menu 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.1">SubMenu 4.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.2">SubMenu 4.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.3">SubMenu 4.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.4">SubMenu 4.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.5">SubMenu 4.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.6">SubMenu 4.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.7">SubMenu 4.7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.8">SubMenu 4.8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.9">SubMenu 4.9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.10">SubMenu 4.10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.11">SubMenu 4.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.12">SubMenu 4.12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Menu 5">Menu 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.1">SubMenu 5.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.2">SubMenu 5.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.3">SubMenu 5.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.4">SubMenu 5.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.5">SubMenu 5.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.6">SubMenu 5.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.7">SubMenu 5.7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.8">SubMenu 5.8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.9">SubMenu 5.9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.10">SubMenu 5.10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.11">SubMenu 5.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.12">SubMenu 5.12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is css

```
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 0.4em;
    height:1.4em; line-height:1.4em;
    position:relative;
}

nav li.sub:after { content:'\25ba'; float:right; vertical-align:middle; font-size:50% }

nav > ul > li     { cursor:default }
nav li ul         { display:none }
nav li li         { display:block; width:8em }
nav li:hover > ul { display:block; position:absolute; top:1.4em;    left:-1px; width:8em; z-index:10 }
nav li li:hover ul{ left:8em; top:-1px }

nav li       { color:black; background:#C2C2C2; border:1px solid #121314; }
nav li li    { color:black; background:#C2C2C2; border-color:#696 }
nav li li li { color:black; background:#C2C2C2; border-color:#669 }

nav li:hover       { background:#828282; color:#fee }
nav li li:hover    { background:#828282; color:#efe }
nav li li li:hover { background:#828282; color:#eef }

nav li li { border-top-width:0 }
nav li li:first-child { border-top-width:1px }
```

look at this picture for more understanding!
[image: picture]

any help is appreciated and any further detail will be provided in needed. thanks

Comment: Just wanted you to know that I've edited your god damn mess of a code that is UN-readable to anyone trying to help. Posts here requesting help should be proper readable in order to not give people helping any further work. I'm also posting a solution soon.

Comment: thanks for your reviewed and sorry for my mess! next time i will take care.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you had assigned a couple of positions wrong (relative and then give the li too much sizes. Also you needed to assign that the last li's will need to be display: block whilst the first ones are inline-block.

```
nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
}

nav li li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/filipetedim/duagvm3h/9/

Comment: thanks for your ans but i forgot to mention that i have a single page site that loads pages dynamically into a div with jquery ajax and those pages only contains some contents that i want there and there are no other extra contents or html tags like `<html>` `<head>` or `<body>` etc. so what i want? suppose when i click on `Menu 1` and when `Menu 1` loaded then their submenu like `SubMenu 1.1 upto  SubMenu 1.12` should be opened in that page horizontally at the same time `menu 1` must remains active! please look at picture i just add to the post.

Comment: please read my question again because i just edited it and please try to understand what really i want! more over i added a picture also.

Comment: So what you want is, when you click a menu, it will show another menu on the side but horizontally?